# WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL() prompting when it shouldn't

Tags: swift, wkextension

I am developing an extension of an iPhone App for Apple Watch (written in Swift running WatchOS2.2, Xcode 7.3, testing on a physical device)

I am running into an issue where I expect no prompt/confirmation on the Apple Watch when calling the tel schema for the following function:

```
WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(NSURL(string:"tel:1231231234"))
```

I am not calling the telprompt function as my understanding is that this is not supported directly by Apple however it seems to be behaving as if it is telprompt. Interestingly enough, telprompt doesn't work.

I am expecting this to directly call the phone number without the prompt on the Apple Watch, however it is first prompting the user displaying a **Cancel** button on the top left, the number in the middle of the screen, and a **Call** button at the bottom. **This also doesn't appear to be picking up the localization on the system (french for example) so it is always displaying Cancel and Call in English.**

[Image of Cancel, Number, and Call being prompted when French in the system language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmtBw.png)

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I haven't found much talk about it on the web. Or is this a known issues? Again, I don't see any bugs reported for it.

---

### Fix Found for the Localization - See Below

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough I was able to get the localization working.

The fix for it was that my Target for my Watch and WatchExtension needed to be checked off for my Launch Images (or splash screen images, or commonly left as "default.png"). Previously my Launch Images were for the app Target only.

I have no idea why the localization seemed to be require my launch images be added to the Watch and WatchExtension targets.

This did not resolve the prompting as it still took place - however since it was at least presenting the correct language this was good for us.